# Increasing the size of differential backups

Tags: dbcc

I have a DB in which some transaction remains open that is increasing the size of differential backups, I had to kill those transaction frequently, I want to drill down to the transaction and find out why it is remaining open so I am running some DMVs to achieve this task but to no avail. Following are the commands :

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

Oldest active transaction:

```
SPID (server process ID) : 17s
UID (user ID)            : -1
Name                     : Set File Size
LSN                      : (357764:44144:5)
Start Time               : July 17 2015 9:32:43:240 AM
```

Replicated Transaction Information:

```
Oldest distributed LSN : (0:0:0)
Oldest non-distributed LSN : (357472:25:1)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error message, contact your system administrator.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: what is the sql server version along with build no are you running ? Also what is `select log_reuse_wait_desc,name from sys.databases` for the database in question ?

Comment: I am using sql server 2005.